# How to pass method name as query string in URL when executing REST api?

Tags: php, rest, api, postman

I am working with REST api's and I want to test these API's by calling them in a REST client (I am using postman)

```
http://localhost/flat_booking_again/api/api.php
```

Above is the url where all my api's reside, I want to call a particular api by passing the api name in the url like this

```
http://localhost/flat_booking_again/api/api.php?method=insertBooking
```

Cany anyone help me out on how I can achieve this?

I am fairly new to using web services api's pardon me if this question seems silly. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: You can select the HTTP method from dropdown in postman which is located before the URL bar. By default GET method will be selected. You can that.

Comment: URI must be nouns, not verbs. Read this quick reference: https://gist.github.com/odan/1d2ef018adb3ea5a0d3abb35406d2c65

Comment: I suspect, like many people, what you actually have is an RPC API, which is fine, but it's not REST. But if we ignore the "REST" part, the question still doesn't make sense. What is it you are having trouble with? How to type that URL into Postman? How to read the `method` parameter from the query string? How to structure your PHP code so that that parameter chooses the action to run? How to test some existing PHP code, which you haven't shown us?

Comment: @IMSoP I am having trouble with how to read the `method` parameter from the query string.

Comment: You can read the `method` parameter with `$method = $_GET['method'];`.

Comment: @DanielO this works ! dunno why I did not think of it before !

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood what REST API is. You should probably go ahead and read it. This [video](https://vimeo.com/17785736) will help you with that.

In REST API you do not use method name to insert a booking.

You would perform a `PUT` request to `http://localhost/api/bookings` to insert a booking.

The REST API is convention based and are triggered by various HTTP methods.

If you want to work with a `booking` object, then you would have a api endpoint as follows:

`http://localhost/api/bookings`

Then you would use HTTP methods to trigger actions on the endpoint.

```
PUT    - /bookings/1    - Update booking with id 1
POST   - /bookings      - Create new booking
DELETE - /bookings/1    - Remove a booking with id 1
GET    - /bookings/1    - Get booking with id 1
GET    - /bookings      - List all booking
```

You can use some REST API library to create implement your routes and api.

Comment: I know. But I need to call specific api's from the api.php file in order to test them. I want to know how to specify to the REST client like postman which api to call .

Comment: Before you can call a rest api, you need a rest api. Your API is not restful. I suggest you to read about it.

Answer (score 0):

the rest API has not the same philisophy as a SOAP WS.

In the case of REST architecture, you must think your service as CRUD service.
Create is equivalent to POST verb
Read is do with the GET verb.
Update => PUT
Delete => delete.

And in your case, your URL msut design your object and not your service.
The notion of method desapears in profit of object oriented.

see this example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer